# How do you put a value in an input text?

Tags: python

```
    ticket = [0 for f in range(11)]
    x=0
    for i in range(10):
      x = x+1
      ticket[x] = int(input("INPUT-",x,":"))
```

> i want to make the input look like "INPUT-1: ","INPUT-2:" following
> the x in the loop

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
ticket = [0 for f in range(11)]
x=0
for i in range(10):
  x = x+1
  ticket[x] = int(input("INPUT-" + str(x) + ":"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, im a newbie trying to help my bro to get his homework done :D

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use an `f-string` to format the output:

```
input(f'INPUT-{x}:')
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the comma `,` with a plus sign `+`, but then you are gonna run into a problem which is that you cant concatenate str to int, so you have to cast it to string by `str()`

```
    ticket[x] = int(input("INPUT-"+str(x)+":"))
```